# How i can edit sip message's header parameters (android-ngn-stack)

Tags: android, sip, telecommunication, ims

i'm making an android IMS client using android-ngn-stack , so i wanna to modifi some header parameters so how i can edit in this headers and remove parameter , add parameter , modifi parameter .

thanks a lot ,[for example , how can i set max forwards to 100 instead of 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMnHV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max forwards value can be set using the method 'setMaxFDs' in the SipStack class:

```js
  public boolean setMaxFDs(long max_fds) {
    return tinyWRAPJNI.SipStack_setMaxFDs(swigCPtr, this, max_fds);
  }
```

Comment: what if i need to add or remove parameter in mandatory header like via header ?